# how to toggle() a element thats centred in a div, it always starts at the left, later skipps

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with my `.toggle()`, as I got a container and it got a div inside that is hidden. I have used `.toggle()` to show and hide it, but because of some reason the div always starts to show in the left corner and when it completely shown it's possition itself centred

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q56yM/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="click_me">click me</a>
<div class="contain">
<div id="drop_down"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#drop_down {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contain {
    width: 100%;
    text-align;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function() {
    $('#drop_down').toggle('slow'); 
});​
```

Comment: You can also use something like `slideToggle`, `fadeToggle`. The both work in the same way was `toggle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change html like this

```
<a href="#" id="click_me">click me</a>
<div class="contain">
   <div class="content"><div id="drop_down"></div></div>
</div>​
```

and add this style

```
.content{
  margin: 0 auto;width:200px;  
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/q56yM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle("slow")` is using the jquery toggle effect which is working exactly as expected in your fiddle. If you want to use different transitions, you need to look at the jqueryui effects.

Here is a demo and list of different effects for `.toggle()` using jqueryui
http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/

The core behavior of `.toggle()` doesn't allow for an effects parameter, only duration, optional easing and callback.

Comment: the transition does not matter that much, its the div that makes the skip from left to right after its done. 

`margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I thought the issue was how it was transitioning and not the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Its the style margin :0 auto places the div to the center.